# Can't read key?

Tags: vb.net

Ok so I am making this system information application that runs on the desktop, but for some reason this gives me an error.

Error: [ArgumentException was unhandled] Registry key name must start with a valid base key name.

I can see the registry is there.

```html
        Dim readValue As String
        readValue = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue _
       ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\SYSTEM\CentralProcessor\3","ProcessorNameString",Nothing)
        Label9.Text = CStr(readValue)
```

Edit: This sight just helped me, there was 2 Unicode chars in there.

Comment: you are reinventing the wheel - there are at least 6 good SysInfo apps on CodeProject

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with program permission ,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE needs administrator access, in app.manifest

Change 

to